# SSIS XML encoding error

Tags: xml, ssis

I get the below error on the SSIS XML Source. Can anyone help me to resolve the issue please.

**[Customer Master [2]] Error: The Customer Master was unable to process the XML data. Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 55979, position 10.**

after doing more research I have discovered there is a "hidden" character. The character is a non breaking space. Is the non breaking space a valid XML 
character as per the XML specification https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets. The non breaking space has a hex ascii value of xA0.

```
Char       ::=      #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]  /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
```

Comment: Your error message literally tells you which character in the XML data is invalid.

Comment: For the given encoding. Is there a way to change the encoding or specify the encoding in SSIS? As I still want to process the character that is been specified as invalid.

Comment: The encoding comes from the XML file, not SSIS. You can use XSLT (via the XML Task) to transform the file into a different encoding. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp